# OAuth2 with third party clients

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, jwt

i was reading up on OAuth2. As I understand it is meant for *access delegation*, so a user signing up for a service like Stack Overflow (SO), can allow SO to use his Google, Facebook, etc. accounts for authenticating on SO. Additionally SO will have limited access to his Google/Facebook accounts

Suppose, if I want to build a 3rd party client to any of the popular services. For the sake of discussion, say a website that is a client of the SO APIs. This site will have it's own authentication/authorization in addition to Stack Overflow's. To make things complicated, suppose my site also allows the user to signup using Google, Facebook and other OAuth providers.
How will OAuth2 help here. What will the authentication & authorization process look like?

Thanks

Vikas